# how to switch touchscreen keyboard to split touchscreen ergonomic keyboard

Tags: 20.04, keyboard-layout, touchscreen

i am using ubuntu 20.04. i want my touchscreen keyboard layout to look like [enter link description here](https://www.groovypost.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/win-8.png)
how do i do this?

Comment: The screenshot is from Windows so... use Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Onboard** is a linux on-screen keyboard and you can edit your layout.

[image: onboard-config]

Click 'New' and duplicate an existing format. Or you can make it from scratch.

Enjoy building own thing!